# Why use maven if already using git?

Tags: git, maven

As I understand, maven pulls in dependencies.  But, if I already pull in the dependent jars once and park them in git, why do I need maven?

Even if there are multiple developers, once the dependencies are in git, each developer will get all the dependencies when they pull the git repo, so where is the need for maven?

I understand this question might be deemed "opinion based", but I am trying to understand what advantage maven provides if the dependencies are already in source control.

EDIT:  I am talking about fixed, third party dependencies like jersey, jackson, etc., not project jars.

Comment: well how about when you add a new dependency and that dependency is dependent on something else ? With maven this would automatically be taken care of.

Comment: Besides the general difference, that Maven is more a build tool, just think of a large app, having 100 dependencies (and there might be circular dependencies between some of them). Would you like to blow them up your repository from the size of some 100KB to 100MB or even more?

Comment: Unless you plan on editing the dependencies, there's no real reason to put them in `git`. Keep build control and source control separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use a pair of scissors if already using a hammer?

Git is a **Source** Code Management system, Maven is a **binary** artifact management and build system.

Putting binary dependencies into an SCM is considered bad practice, and it's a waste of network and storage resources.

When someone clones your repo and builds it, it's typically not their first Maven build, so there's a good chance that many transitive dependencies of your project will already be in their local repository, so they won't have to download these dependencies again.

Comment: "Maven is a binary artifact management system"? Are you sure you're not thinking of artifactory or nexus?

Comment: Even standalone Maven manages binary artifacts in your local repo (besides doing a few other things...). But of course Maven is best used in combination with a repository manager like Nexus.